# Kubectl run command with nodeSelector and tolerations

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubectl

I am using Kubectl run command to execute pod on a specific node.

```
kubectl --namespace=ns run pod1 --image image1 \
  --overrides='{"spec":{"nodeSelector":{"appgroup":"app1"}}}' \
  --command python3 script.py
```

Sometimes pod is going on pending status and it cannot progress to running phase.

How can I add tolerations to the run command?

Note: I do not have a yaml file.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this adding a "tolerations" array.

If you want to ignore all tolerations, we can do this with an "operator=exists" condition.

```
kubectl --namespace=$your_ns run $your_pod --image $your_image \
  --overrides='{"spec":{"nodeSelector":{"appgroup":"app1"},"tolerations":[{"operator":"exists"}]}}' \
  --command python3 script.py \
  [--dry-run=client -o yaml]
```

Also note: if you want to use a YAML file, the "dry-run" and "-o yaml" option would help you generate a first copy. Maybe you would be more comfortable with a plaintext file testing your changes.